# Asymptotics of logarithms of functions

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

If I know that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, does it follow that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}=1$ as well? I see that this definitely doesn't hold for $\dfrac{e^{f(x)}}{e^{g(x)}}$ (take $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$), but I'm not sure how to handle the other direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the asymptotic equality of the logarithms doesn't follow. Consider

$$f(x) = 1 + \frac1x;\quad g(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Ignoring lower-order terms, we have

$$\frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)} = \frac{1/x + O(x^{-2})}{1/x^2 + O(x^{-4})} \sim \frac{1/x}{1/x^2} = x.$$

However, from $f \sim g$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log f(x) - \log g(x) = 0,$$

so if $f$ and $g$ stay away from $1$, you have an even stronger result than mere asymptotic equality.

Comment: Your last statement was what I was looking for, thanks! I'm not quite sure why being near 1 is problematic, besides the fact that dividing by $\log g(x)$ looks bad. Could you explain more about this?

Comment: The problem is that $\log$ has a zero at $1$. If you have two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ with $a_n - b_n \to 0$, you know that $a_n$ and $b_n$ have approximately the same size, unless they are close to $0$. When two numbers are close to $0$, their relative magnitudes can be hugely different, although their difference is small.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this answer -- why does ignoring lower order terms yield $\frac {\log f(x)}{\log g(x)} = \frac {1/x} {1/x^2}$? Aren't $x^{-1}$ and $x^{-2}$ the lower order terms here, so ignoring lower order terms yields $\frac {\log 1} {\log 1}$?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Ignoring the lower order terms of the logarithms, $$\log \left(1 + \tfrac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{3x^3} - \dotsc$$ and similar for $\log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)$. The ignored $O(x^{-2})$ resp. $O(x^{-4})$ remainders don't influence the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, okay, thank you -- so you're referring to the Taylor series expansion of $\log$?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Yes. That gives the asymptotic expansions of $\log f(x)$ and $\log g(x)$, which are what we need.

Answer (score 0):

It does not follow. Take the example of $f(x)=e^{-x}+1$ and $g(x)=1$. Then 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x}+1}{1}=1
$$
However, 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(e^{-x}+1)}{\log 1}
$$
Does not exist.